# proper php/html reference to function

Tags: php

i got it to work like this 
Class: 
     class useraccount{
                private $username;
                private $lastname;
                private $firstname;

```
    public function userProfileView ()
    {
            $varViewUser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
                $varusername = $_SESSION['username'];
                $varViewUserProfile = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$varusername'");
                      while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($varViewUserProfile)) {
                      $this->username = $rows['username'];
                      $this->firstname = $rows['user_firstname'];
                      $this->lastname = $rows['user_lastname'];
                      $this->email = $rows['email'];
                    }

            return $this->lastname;
            return $this->firstname;

    } 
  }
```

HTML:

First Name : userProfileView(); ?>

Now how do i reference which value to be shown?

Comment: You need to go back to the books and review variable scoping. You've got it all messed up.

Comment: You might need to start your session (http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) unless you have not set `session.auto_start` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start) to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables in PHP are always local to functions.

Suggest you rewrite to

```
class useraccount{


  private $username;

  public function getUsername()
  {
    return $this->username;
  }

  public function userProfileView ()
  {
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($varViewUser)) {
      $this->username  = $rows['username'];
        $Firstname = $rows['user_firstname'];
        $lastname = $rows['user_lastname'];
        $email = $rows['email'];
    }
  }


  include ('user_functions.php') ;$varuser = new useraccount; echo $varuser->getUsername();
```

Comment: try my edit. You still need to check my syntax as well. I'm just giving you tips here

Comment: Thanks for your effort, i did notice the extra =. but i still have the issue.